# Modifying duplicate if-else statements into a cleaner code

Tags: java, if-statement

Im making a calculator Gui. Is there any way to make this code look cleaner without duplicating lines.

```
double num1, num2, ans, doub;
num1 = Double.parseDouble(FirstInput.getText());
num2 = Double.parseDouble(SecondInput.getText());
oper = (Operator.getText());

if(oper.equals("+")){
    ans = num1 + num2;
    doub = Math.round(ans * 100000.0) / 100000.0;
    if(doub == (int) ans){
        Answer.setText(Integer.toString((int) ans));
    } else{
        Answer.setText(Double.toString(doub));
    }
}
if(oper.equals("-")){
    ans = num1 - num2;
    doub = Math.round(ans * 100000.0) / 100000.0;
    if(doub == (int) ans){
        Answer.setText(Integer.toString((int) ans));
    } else{
        Answer.setText(Double.toString(doub));
    }
}
if(oper.equals("/")){
    ans = num1 / num2;
    doub = Math.round(ans * 100000.0) / 100000.0;
    if(doub == (int) ans){
        Answer.setText(Integer.toString((int) ans));
    } else{
        Answer.setText(Double.toString(doub));
    }
}
if(oper.equals("x")){
    ans = num1 * num2;
    doub = Math.round(ans * 100000.0) / 100000.0;
    if(doub == (int) ans){
        Answer.setText(Integer.toString((int) ans));
    } else{
        Answer.setText(Double.toString(doub));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your last three (six after the edit) lines in every statement are the same. You could make a method out of that calling it in the if's or just put it outside of the if statements to not duplicate your code there.

Comment: You can use a switch case here, and then write a method as @Ben suggested to which takes the operator & operands...

Comment: also: a switch, or at least an if else if approach would be better. in your code, even if your first if statement returns true, the following if statements will (needlessly) still be validated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With java-8 you could make it quite fancy by introducing a new method which accepts the numbers and an `DoubleBinaryOperator`:

```
public void setAnswerText(double num1, double num2, DoubleBinaryOperator operator){
    final double ans = operator.applyAsDouble(num1, num2);
    final double doub = Math.round(ans * 100000.0) / 100000.0;
    if(doub == (int) ans){
        Answer.setText(Integer.toString((int) ans));
    } else{
        Answer.setText(Double.toString(doub));
    }
}
```

and using a switch statement:

```
final double num1 = Double.parseDouble(FirstInput.getText());
final double num2 = Double.parseDouble(SecondInput.getText());
final String oper = (Operator.getText());
final DoubleBinaryOperator operator;
switch(oper){
    case "+": 
        operator = (a, b) -> a+b;
        break;
    case "-": 
        operator = (a, b) -> a-b;
        break;
    case "/": 
        operator = (a, b) -> a/b;
        break;
    case "x": 
        operator = (a, b) -> a*b;
        break;
    default:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

setAnswerText(num1, num2, operator);
```

That way, you're finding the matching operator in the switch-statment and then executing the method with the numbers and the found operator

Comment: why the Java-8 mention? this was possible in older versions as well

Comment: I found out that my code is inside a method. Is it ok to place the setAnswerText method 200 lines away from where it will be used?

Comment: @Stultuske, well the use of the lambda expression only works with Java 8 and upwards

Comment: @Lino read the description you added to it, without looking at (all) the code

Comment: @Stultuske happens often to me, just reading some bits and then throw in some comments, but later I have to retract ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the part where you prepare the answer into a separate method, so you do not need to write that code multiple times, e.g.

```
private static void prepAnswer(double ans){
    double doub = Math.round(ans * 100000.0) / 100000.0;
    if(doub == (int) ans){
        Answer.setText(Integer.toString((int) ans));
    } else{
        Answer.setText(Double.toString(doub));
    }
}
```

Additionally, you could use a switch-case statement. That would look like this:

```
    String oper = (Operator.getText());
    switch(oper) {
        case "+": prepAnswer(num1 + num2); break;
        case "-": prepAnswer(num1 - num2); break;
        case "/": prepAnswer(num1 / num2); break;
        case "x": prepAnswer(num1 * num2); break;    
        default: throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
```

Comment: safest (and cleanest) would be to add a default case to the switch

Comment: @Stultuske: true, I added one.

Answer (score 0):

Just consolidating

```
    double num1, num2, ans, doub;
    num1 = Double.parseDouble(FirstInput.getText());
    num2 = Double.parseDouble(SecondInput.getText());
    oper = (Operator.getText());

    switch(oper){
    case "+" :  ans = num1 + num2; break;
    case "-" :  ans = num1 - num2; break;
    case "/" :  ans = num1 / num2; break;
    case "*" :  ans = num1 * num2; break;
    }
    setAnswer(ans);
}

    /**
     * @param ans
     */
    private static void setAnswer(double ans) {
        double doub;
        doub = Math.round(ans * 100000.0) / 100000.0;
        if (doub == (int) ans) {
            Answer.setText(Integer.toString((int) ans));
        } else {
            Answer.setText(Double.toString(doub));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked Lino's answer to use DoubleBinaryOperator .(+1) for that. Most ifs or switch  can be replaced by polymorphism . Functions without ifs/switch are easier to read/test and maintain . Greatly influenced from this google talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc
You can use  this ENUM version as well . You need JDK 8 for this

```
public enum Operation {

    PLUS("+", (x, y) -> x + y),

    MINUS("-", (x, y) -> x - y),

    MULTIPLY("*", (x, y) -> x * y),

    DIVIDE("/", (x, y) -> x / y);

    private final DoubleBinaryOperator op;
    private final String symbol;

    public double apply(double x, double y) {
        return op.applyAsDouble(x, y);
    }

    Operation(String symbol, DoubleBinaryOperator op) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.op = op;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public static void setAnswerText(double num1, double num2, Operation operator) {
        final double ans = operator.apply(num1, num2);
        final double doub = Math.round(ans * 100000.0) / 100000.0;
        if (doub == (int) ans) {

            Answer.setText(Integer.toString((int) ans));
        } else {

            Answer.setText(Double.toString(doub));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final double num1 = 100;
        final double num2 = 200;
        final Operation oper = Operation.PLUS;
        setAnswerText(num1, num2, oper);

    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to make `Operation` implement `DoubleBinaryOperator` as you're already providing the `apply` function